# Negating 64 Bit Number in 32 Bit Maschine

Tags: assembly, x86

How can I negate a 64-bit number in x86 that is stored in two 32-bit registers?

Comment: Use any of the usual methods. Subtract from zero but mind the carry. Invert the bits, add one, mind the carry.

Comment: @Jester how do I mind the carry in this situation?

Comment: You can do it the following way: Negate both registers independently. If the register holding the low 32 bits is zero, this is the result. If it is not zero, you must decrement (= subtract 1 from) the (result in the) register holding the high 32 bits.

Comment: An easy way to implement @Martin’s algorithm is `neg high; neg low; sbc high, 0`

Comment: Another way requires only two operations but uses another register: `xor dest, dest; neg low; sbc dest, high`. (This puts the high part of the result in `dest` and leaves the low part in `low`.)